# How do you copy a file into an NTFS alternate data stream in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, ntfs, alternate-data-stream

I'm trying to create a proof of concept of an example I saw in a textbook for one of my cybersecurity classes.  I set up the required files and tried it but I only am getting errors.

This is the example:

```
C:\> type C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe > c:\windows\system32\calc.exe:notepad.exe
```

This is what I did:

```
C:\> type c:\hello.exe > c:\README.txt:hello.exe
```

where `hello.exe` is an executable that prints `hello world`, and `README.txt` is a text file with some random text in it.

The error I get is:

```
out-file: The given path's format is not supported.
```

when there is a space between the first parameter and the redirectional operator, and

```
Get-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\README.txt:hello.exe'.
```

when there is no space.

I've tried replacing `type` with `cat`, adding and removing spaces between operators, creating the alternate stream before trying to import the data, and different file types.  Also, tangent question, I'm having trouble getting `::$DATA` to work on NTFS files.  It just gives the `cat : Cannot find path 'C:\hello.exe::' because it does not exist.`

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell `type`, `cat` or `gc` are all just *aliases* to [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1), which work with **texts** by default, so obviously you can't use them for binary data (In cmd `type` also just works with texts). To work with binary files you must use `-Encoding Byte` or `-AsByteStream` to tell `Get-Content` to not deal with the file as text

Besides you can't use redirection to save the output because [`>` is just an alias to `Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1), which doesn't support streams. You must specify the stream to store with the `-Stream` option in [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7.1)

```
Get-Content -Encoding Byte "C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe" | `
    Set-Content -Encoding Byte -Stream Notepad .\README.txt
```

In fact lots of cmdlets in PowerShell like [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item?view=powershell-7.3), [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.1), [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.3), [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7.1), [`Clear-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/clear-content?view=powershell-7.3), [`Add-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content?view=powershell-7.3) have the **`-Stream` option** to operate on streams. Unfortunately [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1) doesn't have this option

See also [Interact with Alternate Data Streams](http://powershellcookbook.com/recipe/XilI/interact-with-alternate-data-streams)